# How to write function in script and then call the function in notebook?

Tags: function-construction

In the script, I would like to define a function called function_name, with variable x, and the function is defined to multiply the input with $2$.

I would like to have something like this in notebook:
$\text{function_name}(x)=2*x$

It is kind of Matlab skill, and I find that Mathematica is slightly different from it. I am asking this question is because in my Mathematica code, I have a lot of the same actions repeating on multiple different inputs, and I don't want to copy lines and lines again just in order to doing the same thing for one input.

Anyone could help? Thanks a lot!

Here is my code

```
B = {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};
IncidenceGraph[B];
vec = {a, b, c, 0};
trigs = B . Sin[Transpose[B] . vec];
polys = TrigExpand /@ trigs /. {Sin[a] -> sa, Sin[b] -> sb, 
    Sin[c] -> sc, Cos[a] -> ca, Cos[b] -> cb, Cos[c] -> cc};
allfuns = 
  Join[polys, {sa^2 + ca^2 - 1, sb^2 + cb^2 - 1, sc^2 + cc^2 - 1}];
gb = GroebnerBasis[allfuns, {sa, sb, sc}, {ca, cb, cc}];
sol = Reduce[gb == 0] /. {sa -> Sin[a], sb -> Sin[b], sc -> Sin[c], 
    ca -> Cos[a], cb -> Cos[b], cc -> Cos[c]};
oldeqns = And @@ Thread[trigs == 0];
neweqns = FullSimplify[oldeqns && sol];
result = 
 Reduce[neweqns && 0 <= a <= 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b <= 2 \[Pi] && 
    0 <= c <= 2 Pi, {a, b, c}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

The matrix $B$ is input, and output is *result*.

Comment: 3 ways to do this: Function_name[x]=2x; Function_name= 2#&; Function_name=Function[{x}, 2x]. In addition you can either use Set(=) what evaluates the right hand side at once, or SetDelayed, what evaluates the right hand side each time it is used.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you Huber. I found it seems difficult to transfer your suggestion on my code, since in my case, there are lots of actions to take, on the input, not just multiplying $2$. Thus I add my code in the description of my question..

Comment: Your code does not run. It gives an error.

Comment: @DanielHuber I just edited the code. How about now? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code packed into a function. (Btw, do not use names with a capital first letter, they are used by the system)

```
myFun[B_] := 
 Module[{a, b, c, sa, ca, sb, cb, cc, vec, trigs, polys, allfuns, gb, 
   sol, oldeqns, neweqns},
  vec = {a, b, c, 0};
  trigs = B . Sin[Transpose[B] . vec];
  polys = 
   TrigExpand /@ trigs /. {Sin[a] -> sa, Sin[b] -> sb, Sin[c] -> sc, 
     Cos[a] -> ca, Cos[b] -> cb, Cos[c] -> cc};
  allfuns = 
   Join[polys, {sa^2 + ca^2 - 1, sb^2 + cb^2 - 1, sc^2 + cc^2 - 1}];
  gb = GroebnerBasis[allfuns, {sa, sb, sc}, {ca, cb, cc}];
  sol = Reduce[gb == 0] /. {sa -> Sin[a], sb -> Sin[b], sc -> Sin[c], 
     ca -> Cos[a], cb -> Cos[b], cc -> Cos[c]};
  oldeqns = And @@ Thread[trigs == 0];
  neweqns = FullSimplify[oldeqns && sol];
  Reduce[neweqns && 0 <= a <= 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b <= 2 \[Pi] && 
     0 <= c <= 2 Pi, {a, b, c}, Reals] // FullSimplify
  ]

b = {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};
myFun[b]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to not show $ \$ 5468$?

Comment: The ending $6568 is added because these variables are localized. To prevent this you may e.g. use global variables from the beginning (do not mention them in the first argument of Module) or you could replace the localized variables by global ones using "ReplaceAll"

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Save`:

```
f1[x_] := 2*x
Save["your_directory/functions.m", "`*"];
```

To call in a notebook,

```
In[1]:= Get["your_directory/functions.m"];

In[2]:= f1[1]

Out[2]= 2
```

Comment: Thank you! What if my code is not simply multiply $2$? I just edited (add the code) the description of my question.